# Laravel 5 - route types

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Couldn't think of a more descriptive title.

Here's the dilemma, I'm wondering if anybody has a good approach to this or if I've overlooked something obvious?

Picture these two routes:

```
/category/product
/parent/child
```

The first route deals with products in a shop.
The second route deals with regular pages in the CMS.

How do I distinguish between these two routes in my application? I don't want to append something before each route (ie /shop/category/product, /page/parent/child) if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

in your routes.php file put this code

```
 Route::get('/{action?}/{name?}',[
        'uses' =>'NiceActionController@getNiceAction',
        'as' =>'niceaction'
    ]);
```

then go to controller folder and create a file NiceActionController then :

```
 <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;
class NiceActionController extends Controller
{
    public function getNiceAction($action,$name=null)
    {
        return view('actions.'.$action , ['name' => $name]) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to supply the action inside the URL here, which isn't what I need.

By /category/product - category would be the actual category name, and product would be the actual product name.

Does that make sense?

Comment: simply you can change product with action text

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to just stack the routes:

```
Route::get('category/{product}', 'Controller@function');
Route::get('{parent}/{child}', 'Controller@function');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group your routes.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'parent'], function () {
 Route::get('child', 'Controller1@action1');
 Route::get('anotherchild', 'Controller2@action2');
});
```

This gives you routes `/parent/child` and `/parent/anotherchild`.

There are more options, read more at [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-groups)